# Aggregation of results and conditional fields

Tags: drupal

I have created a  drupal view for label printing

View shows in like this

Omang Kumar              Mehul Khanna             Ganesh Kumar    //name
A 86 Krishna             A 21 Brooklyn            A 86 Krishna    // address
Lucknow                  San Fransico             Lucknow         //city
Uttar Pradesh            California               Uttar Pradesh   //state
India                    United States of America India           //country

1. Name,address,city,state,country are all fields of contact type
2. If country is India then do not display the same
3. If person has same address,city,state and country then it should aggregated as

Omang Kumar
Ganesh Kumar
A 86 Krishna 
Lucknow
Uttar Pradesh

I am using drupal 7

Answer (score 0):

Use an unformatted or html list of fields. You could then add a class to the country field in the Style accordion within the field settings using the Country field as the class. Then just add css to hide the class india.

You can then use group by in the format settings and group by the address.